# React router app hosted in firebase, child routes returns 404

Tags: firebase, react-router, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I have a create react app, hosted in Firebase. I'm using `react-router-dom`.

Everything work as expected if I request the root route '/'. Then I can request child routes.

But if I'm a new user or go to a private tab and try to hit a child route directly. It returns a 404 not found page :

[image]

Here is a sample of my Router :

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={UserDashboard} exact />
        <Route path="/email-link-sign-up" component={EmailLinkSignUp} exact />
        <Route path="/join-with-hash" component={JoinClubHash} exact />
        <Route component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this rule in `hosting` attribute in the `firebase.json` file did the trick :

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

It basically says "Every child paths should serve `index.html` file"